# opencv python what kind of array should I pass to setSVMdetector

Tags: python, opencv, svm

I am trying to use hog+svm in opencv python.

there is a function, setSVMdetector.

When I save a svm and load it to use as a parameter for setSVMdetector, the function gives me an error.

I found that I need to parse data from saved svm file.

There is a question.

I don't have any idea how or which data I should use.

In what format, what data should I use?